# Which debugger VScode used for debug C++ on windows

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I can debug cpp which is built by msvc build tool on windows with vscode by setting `cppvsdbg` attribute in launch.json.

The question is: Which debugger vscode will use. I mean what is the exe name?

Or: What is the default debugger in windows with msvc build tool?

Purpose: I have qt5 lib which is build by msvc from source. I need to config the proper debugger for qtcreator .

Comment: it's the debugger coming along with the compiler (gdb for gcc, lldb for llvm, CDB/NTSD for MSVC)

Comment: So how to call native msvc debugger in cmd? I indeed installed msvc build tool from Visual studio installer along with windows 10 SDK. But searched whole disk, and sure there is no cdb.exe or ntsd.exe. I am wondering How vscode did?

Comment: I have no idea because I've never tried them in VS Code. But why don't you just install some extension that configs the compiler and debugger for you? Anyway see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-cdb-and-ntsd and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debuggers-in-the-debugging-tools-for-windows-package for more information about debuggers in Windows. In fact you can even [use lldb for debugging pdb files](https://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html)